# How to I force JSF2 code loaded with $("#widget").load("widget URL") to re-render

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

My client will include this script in his web site to include my widget.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#widget").load("http://XYZ.com/widget.xhtml);
    });
</script>
```

My widget is hosted remotely, running on Tomcat, contains JSF2, EL expressions and needs access to server beans.

What is the best way to force an initial (and then continuous) JSF lifecycle execution after the load into the host site? Right now my widget is coded as a complete xhtml page, and I am developing and testing it by navigating directly to its own URL.

Also, can you point out potential cross-site problems I might encounter? Does using jQuery load minimize them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it with an . As long as my remote widget is called widget.jsf in the iframe src attribute, the JSF lifecycle works just fine.